# Selecting a node based on the value of a node in another document

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

If I had a lookup table in XML like this:

```
<lookup>
    <element key='abc'>Hello</element>
</lookup>
```

And another XML file like this:

```
<root>
    <child key='abc'>Goodbye</child>
</root>
```

And I do this XSL transformation after loading the first file into a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="myvar" select="document('lookupfile.xml')/lookup" />
<xsl:value-of select="$myvar/element[@key=/root/child/@key]" />
```

What I want is the value 'Hello' to come up, but instead I get nothing.  Am I not allowed to compare the value of two nodes directly?  Every example I see always compares [@key='hardCodedValue'] and never to the value of another node.

If I hardcode the value like so: select="$myvar/element[@key='abc'] it returns 'Hello'.  If I directly output the value of the root/child key with select="/root/child/@key"  I get the correct value 'abc'.  It's just when I try to do the comparison above that it returns nothing.

Comment: What's the definition of `$myvar`?

Comment: I edited it to include the definition.

Comment: Please post a **complete** example that can be used to reproduce the issue. Your code is taken out of context - and context is crucial in XPath/XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the predicate, the context is the `element` element of the `lookupfile.xml` document, so `/root/child/@key` is going to be evaluated within that document.

You can either do this, with `current()`:

```
<xsl:variable name="myvar" select="document('lookupfile.xml')/lookup" />
<xsl:value-of select="$myvar/element[@key = current()/root/child/@key]" />
```

or store the value in a variable and use that:

```
<xsl:variable name="myvar" select="document('lookupfile.xml')/lookup" />
<xsl:variable name="mykey" select="/root/child/@key" />
<xsl:value-of select="$myvar/element[@key = $mykey]" />
```

Comment: Using current() solved the problem in my simple test example!  It didn't work in my actual XML document, though dumping the value of the '/root/child/@key' equivalent in a variable did.  I'll try and figure out why current() isn't working in my real file, but I think I'm on the right track.  Thanks!